# Maven - IntelIJ - strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6

Tags: java, maven, appium

I'm facing with this issue, the terminal said:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project FloAutomation: Compilation failure
>   [ERROR] /Users/hai/workspaces/automation-for-iPad/src/main/java/Locators/ObjectRepository.java:[19,19] strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
>   [ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)

I have checked the JAVA_HOME and java version they said:

> $JAVA_HOME
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> java version
>
> java -version java version "9.0.4" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (build 9.0.4+11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11,
>   mixed mode)

I also check the project's language level it's 9.0.4

Could you give me some solution to fix this ?
Thanks,

Comment: Did you specify the source and target versions in your compiler's plugin in pom.xml?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele, yes I did, I'm setting 1.6 for source and target

Comment: If you're setting 1.6 of course you can't use java 7 features. Change that to 1.7 or higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `pom.xml`, then refresh maven:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

Since you are using Java 9 the value should be `1.9` or as the error says: `1.7` or above.

Answer (score 1):

Support for `String`-typed switch expressions was only added in Java 7. So the minimum you need to set is `1.7`

Check [this doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for more info.